# How to create a Stream out of IObservable<byte>?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, observable, system.reactive

I've been thinking how to create a bridge between `IObservable<byte>` and `Stream`, but I'm completely lost.

The use case for this is when a function needs you to provide a **Stream**, but you have your data in an **IObservable<Byte>**.

Since the Stream is pull-based and IObservable is push-based, I don't even know if it's feasible to do such a thing without trying calling `byteSequence.ToEnumerable()`.

The problem is that, in order to create a `Stream` out of it, I'd need to do

```cs
new MemoryStream(byteSequence.ToEnumerable().ToArray());
```

This will work, but will need to allocate ALL the bytes in memory and that is a deal breaker for many use cases.

**UPDATE**

I've been inspired by Marc Gravell's comment and I tried my luck up with this code that is using **Pipes**. Apparently, it works! I don't know if it's completely OK, but I've leave here for reference.

```cs
public static Stream ToStream(this IObservable<byte> observable, int bufferSize = 4096)
{
    var pipe = new System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe();

    var reader = pipe.Reader;
    var writer = pipe.Writer;

    observable
        .Buffer(bufferSize)
        .Select(buffer => Observable.FromAsync(async () => await writer.WriteAsync(buffer.ToArray())))
        .Concat()
        .Subscribe(_ => { }, onCompleted: () => { writer.Complete(); }, onError: exception => writer.Complete(exception));

    return reader.AsStream();
}
```

Feel free to improve it.

Comment: You would need to create a custom stream that supports drip feed and have a read/write pukp; however, I wonder whether "pipelines" (System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe) could save you here; Pipe already has this implemented (there's an AsStream or ToStream or similar on PipeReader, IIRC), and it should be pretty trivial to write a pump that reads from IObservable and writes to the PipeWriter - however, honestly I suspect Pipe would be a better mechanism here entirely, rather than forcing IObservable into things (it is designed to act in this capacity)

Comment: More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines

Comment: Big thanks, @MarcGravell. I've edited the OP to add my findings. I've tuned up some code, but I don't know how good it is. Please, review it :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SuperJMN I don't think the order is preserved. The result is scheduled as part of the continuation of task completion, so I think whichever completes first will emit first almost surely. You can test easily with two tasks where the first is long-running and see if they complete out of order. Also, I don't think the async-await in the delegate is necessary. FromAsync takes in a Task and schedules it on the Scheduler using continuations, i.e. so I think async-await here is superfluous. Just go `() => writer.WriteAsync()`.

Comment: @AlexanderHøst Is the order is preserved, then the data in the Stream will potentially be corrupted, right? If so, how to get the correct behavior?

Comment: @SuperJMN I don't really think you can guarantee it without some kind of ordering scheme. Even though PipeWriter appears to be synchronous in practice, the use of FromAsync introduces uncertainty. async and ordered execution are natural enemies. Although it'll probably work in practice, guaranteeing correct order I think will require something more e.g. ensuring each write is synchronously completed before proceeding.

Also, I can't say I love having side-effects in a `Select`.